# Are there any decision problems in NP-Hard whose solution is not verifiable in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

I am going through  complexity classes. Need to clear about NP_Hard problems.

Thanks,
Hareendra

Answer (score 0):

Problems verifiable in polynomial time are in NP. NP is a proper subset of NEXPTIME. Therefore, NEXPTIME\NP is not empty and its problems are not verifiable in polynomial time. By definition, problems in NEXPTIME\NP are NP-hard.

See [Wikipedia - EXPTIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME).